# My id is not null, why do I receive run time error?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ado.net, runtime-error

I get this run time error and my `id` is not null I checked it in my code which you will see and I'm using *telerik `GridView`*

this is the run time error

> The parameterized query '(@_fName nvarchar(4),@_lName nvarchar(2),@_phone nvarchar(6),@_a' expects the parameter '@_id', which was not supplied.

I'm trying to get the `id` from another form that's why I wrote it like this

here's my code in my first layer

```
private void btnEdt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Ref_View_Model = new View_model._View_Model();
        Ref_C = new Customers();

        foreach (var RowInfo in Ref_C.radGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            FireCell = RowInfo.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            if (FireCell==null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("null");
            }
        }

        //Ref_C.radGridView1.CurrentRow.Delete();
        Ref_C.customersTableAdapter.Update(Ref_C.sales_and_Inventory_SystemDataSet);
        Ref_C.customersTableAdapter.Fill(Ref_C.sales_and_Inventory_SystemDataSet.Customers);

        Ref_View_Model.GetEditCustomers(FireCell, txtFName.Text, txtLName.Text, txtPhn.Text, txtDdrss.Text);
}
```

here's my code in the last layer

```
public void EditCustomres( string _id,string _fName, string _lName,string _phone, string _address)
{

        Connection_String = @"Data Source=MOSTAFA-PC;Initial Catalog=" + "Sales and Inventory System" + ";Integrated Security=TrueData Source=MOSTAFA-PC;Initial Catalog=" + "Sales and Inventory System" + ";Integrated Security=True;";
        Query = "update Customers " +
                                "set FName=@_fName  ,LName=@_lName  ,Phone=@_phone ,[Address]=@_address" +" "+
                                  "where Id like @_id";
        using (Con=new SqlConnection(Connection_String))
        using (Cmd=new SqlCommand(Query,Con))
        {
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@_fName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@_lName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@_phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@_address", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@_id", SqlDbType.Int);

            Con = Cmd.Connection;
            Con.Open();

            Cmd.Parameters["@_fName"].Value = _fName;
            Cmd.Parameters["@_lName"].Value = _lName;
            Cmd.Parameters["@_phone"].Value = _phone;
            Cmd.Parameters["@_address"].Value = _address;
            Cmd.Parameters["@_id"].Value = _id;

            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Cmd.Dispose();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't want to use LIKE in this case, unless you have very specific needs for it to update things that look like the ID you're passing in, but are not quite it...

You're passing in `@_id` as an `SqlDbType.Int`, but the variable is actually of type `string`, this will cause a conversion to happen under the hood. In case you're passing in an empty string, the value is converted to `null`, which will result in the error you mentioned in your post. Check the code that leads into calling `EditCustomres` to ensure that it actually passes in the correct value. Adding argument checks, like the one I added, will help you track these kinds of issues much earlier in the callstack.

**Step one** is to get rid of your `LIKE` statement, so please update the query to use:

```
where id = @_id
```

Then update your code, since you expect the `_id` variable to be in int, you can't just assign a string to it, which is probably why it's getting reset to `null`. Either update the method to accept an `int` parameter instead of `string id`, or parse the `int` in your method before adding the parameter:

```
int idValue = -1;
if (!int.TryParse(_id, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out idValue))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("id", "Id must be a string which contains an integer value, the value of 'id' was: '" + _id + "'"); 
}

Cmd.Parameters.Add("@_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idValue;
```

You may need to add a using statement to your file:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

This is where `NumberStyles` and `CultureInfo` are defined. Normally Visual Studio will suggest where you can find these items <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> will pop-up a screen which will add this statement automatically.

---

End result would be:

```
using System.Globalization;

....
....

public void EditCustomers( string _id,string _fName, string _lName,string _phone, string _address)
{
    int idValue = -1;
    if (!int.TryParse(_id, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out idValue))
    {
       string message = "Id must be a string which contains an integer value, the value of 'id' was: '" + _id + "'";
       throw new ArgumentException("_id", message); 
    }

    Connection_String = @"Data Source=MOSTAFA-PC;Initial Catalog=" + "Sales and Inventory System" + ";Integrated Security=TrueData Source=MOSTAFA-PC;Initial Catalog=" + "Sales and Inventory System" + ";Integrated Security=True;";
    Query = @"update Customers 
                  set FName=@_fName, LName=@_lName, Phone=@_phone,[Address]=@_address
                  where Id = @_id";

    using (Con=new SqlConnection(Connection_String))
    using (Cmd=new SqlCommand(Query, con))
    {
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_fName", _fName);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_lName", _lName);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_phone", _phone);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_address", _address);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_id", idValue);

        Con.Open();
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I simplified the code a bit as well. using a verbatim string for your SQL statement, removing the call to `Dispose` (which is already covered by your use of `using(cmd)` and removing the `Con=Cmd.Connection`, since it really cannot have any other value.

Using the `.AddWithValue` method is also easier than creating and setting the value individually.

---

**Be really careful with solutions that require you to concatenate your string to form the SQL query on the SQL Server side**, this could result in the value injecting unwanted SQL statements that can expose your data to the outside world or allow outsiders to destroy your data.

Also be careful with `LIKE` statements for matching update values. Unless you have very strong argument validation on the code paths calling into this statement, passing in `id="?"` or `id="%%"` or simply `id=string.Empty` to your function would likely update all records and will thus overwrite all of them to have the same values. %1% will match 1, 10, 21, 31, 11, 100003... Which is highly unlikely the desired behavior.

Using `=` over `like` in delete and update statements is almost *always* the desired solution. If you get errors with `=` you're likely mixing data types (`string` where `int` is expected for example).

Comment: The Exception that you wrote pops up,what's wrong with my code?

Comment: and also visual studio doesn't know this part       `NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture    `

Comment: In that case you're likely passing in an empty String and not the id of the customer being updated. or it's not a number. Try setting a breakpoint and inspect the value at runtime.

NumberStyles and CultureInfo may require an additional `using System.Globalization;` at the top of your file.

Comment: Updated the answer. And changed the exception message to show the id being passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Your `LIKE` clause for `id` is incorrect. It should be like this:

```
Id LIKE '%' + @_id + '%'
```

Or:

```
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_id","%" + _id+ "%");
```

Or:

```
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "%" + _id + "%";
```

Although it would be better that you use simple `=` instead of `Like`:

```
where Id = @_id
```

Comment: thanks it worked,but can you tell me what is difference between first and second solution? and why this[%] is needed?

Comment: @MostafaBouzari... In second approach there is no need to specify the `SqlDbType`.  And also for `like` you should use `%`.